# 1 to 4 axes ratio in a 3d plot, pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, axis

I have a 3d plot in the domain

```
xmin=0,
xmax=256,
ymin=0,
ymax=1024
```

I want the `y` axis to be longer by 4 compared to the `x` axis, so it looks more like the following (made with Wolfram Mathematica):

[image: correct ratio]

What I have at the moment is this:

[image: plot]

Couldn't find an answer on how to scale the axes in 3d plot. Hope this is not a duplicate.

The farthest I made was to set `scale only axis=true`.

Thanks!

The generating code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    scale only axis=true,
    view={150}{20},
xmin=0,xmax=256,ymin=0,ymax=1024,zmin=0,zmax=130,
]
% Curves
\addplot3+[black, no markers,samples=200, samples y=0,domain=0:1024,variable=\t]
({60}, {\t}, {426803/(6400 + (-512 + \t)^2))});
\addplot3+[black, no markers,samples=200, samples y=0,domain=0:1024,variable=\t]
({100}, {\t}, {810283/(6400 + (-512 + \t)^2))});
\addplot3+[black, no markers,samples=200, samples y=0,domain=0:1024,variable=\t]
({120}, {\t}, {687097/(6400 + (-512 + \t)^2))});
\addplot3+[black, no markers,samples=200, samples y=0,domain=0:1024,variable=\t]
({140}, {\t}, {743646/(6400 + (-512 + \t)^2))});
\addplot3+[black, no markers,samples=200, samples y=0,domain=0:1024,variable=\t]
({180}, {\t}, {607385/(6400 + (-512 + \t)^2))});

% Arrows
\draw[<->] (60, 432, 33.344) -- (60, 592, 33.344);
\draw[<->] (100, 432, 63.3033) -- (100, 592, 63.3033);
\draw[<->] (120, 432, 53.6795) -- (120, 592, 53.6795);
\draw[<->] (140, 432, 58.0974) -- (140, 592, 58.0974);
\draw[<->] (180, 432, 47.452) -- node [midway, below] {$\Delta \lambda$}(180, 592, 47.452);

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What you probably want is [plot box ratio] (page 315).

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thanks a lot! That's what I was looking for.

Comment: @JohnKormylo, do you want to write an answer or shall we close the question as "solved in the comments"?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments.